# Java - Bit Insertion

Tags: java

I have a long number like:

```
long l = Long.parseLong("10*000001111110" , 2) ;
```

Now, I want to add two bits in one position (say 2nd position, marked as *) into the long number.

Like,

```
long l = Long.parseLong("10*11*000001111110" , 2) ; (given between *)
```

Can anybody help me how to do that ? Note that I give an example to illustrate what I want. In real, I have only `long l`and I have to work on it.

Edit:

1) position is not constant may be 0, 1 , 2 .. whatever.

2) and msb's can be 0. Means,

```
long l = Long.parseLong("00000010*000001111110" , 2) ;

long l = Long.parseLong("00000010*11*000001111110" , 2) ;
```

Comment: is this a homework question or does it serve some practical purpose?

Comment: @Woot4Moo, some practical purpose. URL matching.

Comment: Is the specific position constant?  Is it really fixed based on the highest set bit, or could it be specified based on the bit's significance (i.e. 12th-lowest-significant bit)?

Comment: Use bitwise shift operators to do this. Also, as Rob said, it would make it a LOT easier and faster if the position is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea I had is the following:

Extract the first x bits that needs to stay on the position they are (in your example: 10) -> you could do this by running through a loop which creates the appropriate bitmask:

```
long bitmask = 1;
for(long bit = 1; bit < index; bit++) {
    bitmask = (bitmask << 1) | 1;
}
```

Now you can create the long number that gets inserted -> just shift that number index positions to the left.

After that, you can easily build the new number:

```
long number = (((oldNumber >> index) << index) << insertionLength) | (insertion << index) | (oldNumber && bitmask);
```

Note: `((oldNumber >> index) << index)` clears out the right part of the number (this part gets appended at the end using the bistmask). then you just need to shift this result by the length of the insertion (make space for it) and or it with the insertion (this needs to get shifted to the left by the index where to insert: `(insertion << index)`. Finally, or the last part of the number (extracted via the bitmask: `oldNumber && bitmask`) to this result and you are done.

Note: I haven't tested this code. However, generally it should work but you may need to check my shifts (either it is index or index - 1 or so)!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want something like bitStuffing where masking (`&`, `~`, `^`, and `|`) and shifting (`>>` and `<<`) are your instruments of choice.

```
long insertBit(long p_orignal, long p_new_bits, int p_starting_position_from_right, int p_ending_position_from_right)
{
     long returnValue = p_original;
     long onlyNewBits = 0;

     // Set the bit to zero
     long mask = (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFl);
     for (int i=p_starting_position_from_right; i<=p_ending_position_from_right; i++)
     {
          mask ^ (1l << i);
     }
     returnValue = returnValue & mask; 
     mask = ~mask;
     onlyNewBits = ~(p_new_bits & mask);
     returnValue |= onlyNewBits;

     return returnValue;
}
```

Disclaimer: I don't have a Java compiler available to compile this, but it should be something like this.

Comment: For starters, `0 << anything` is a no-op. Maybe you wanted a 1 there.

Comment: Good point, meant to have all 1's except for the zero, will edit

Comment: Thanks. But, I want two bits to inserts like 00, 01 etc.

Comment: @Arpssss  Are the two bits you want to enter consecutive?

Comment: @MartyE, I want to insert two bits which are consecutive. For that, should I call that two times or is it possible to insert in one time.

Comment: @Arpssss  It is possible to change the function to get it down to 1 call.  Though you'd have to pass in a `long` parameter instead and probably pass in two `int` parameters for the `p_starting_position_from_right` and `p_ending_position_from_right` and that way you could make it n-number of bits.  Code is coming right up.

Comment: @Arpssss You'll also probably want to play around with this is your IDE using the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the `Long` value say `123` you need to first convert this to a binary string.  Like so:

```
String binaryValue = Long.toBinaryString("123L");
```

Then we take the string representation and perform a manipulation a specific character like so:

```
char[] characters = binaryValue.toCharArray();  
  char desiredCharacter = characters[index];  
  if(desiredCharacter == '1')  
  {    
       if(newValue == '1')  
       {
           desiredCharacter = '0';  
       }
  }else{
            if(newValue == '1')  
            {
                 desiredCharacter ='1';  
            }  
       }
```

finally we convert the modified characters back into a string like so:

```
String rebuiltString = new String(characters);
```

I am sure there are more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to set a specific bit in a number:

To turn it on:

```
number |=  (1 << pos) 
  if pos = 4:   (1<<pos) =   00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000
```

To turn it off:

```
number &= ~(1 << pos) 
  if pos = 4:   ~(1<<pos) =  11111111 11111111 11111111 11101111
```

where pos is the position of the bit (with 0 being the low order bit, and 64 being the high order bit).